# Download Excel file with multiple sheets from Dash (send_file)

Tags: python, callback, plotly-dash, xlsxwriter

I have been trying to create a Dash board that allows the user to download data separated in different sheets of an Excel file. I have managed to create the Excel file separately, so I know it works, but I am getting error when I try to send the file as an output. I have tried with send_data_frame but it will only return the first data frame with only one sheet.

```
@app.callback(
Output("download-dataframe-xlsx", "data"),
Input("save-button", "n_clicks"),
State("memory-output", "data"),
prevent_initial_call=True)

def download_as_excel(n_clicks, table_data):
    if not n_clicks:
    raise PreventUpdate

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('new_excel_file.xlsx', engine="xlsxwriter")
    for df in table_data:
       copytoexcel = pd.DataFrame(table_data[df])
       copytoexcel.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=df)
    writer.save()

    return send_file(writer,  attachment_filename="testing.xlsx", as_attachment=True)
```

In summary, I have a dictionary called table_data that I am importing from another callback, from this dictionary has a string as keys, and a list as values.
The loop and data work, but once I try to execute it with Dash, the file won't download.

Any help? I have tried sending it as bytes, data_frame, and file with no luck! Also there has been little documentation about it online!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try the [dcc.send_file(...)](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/download) from Dash components :

```
@app.callback(
    Output("download-dataframe-xlsx", "data"),
    Input("save-button", "n_clicks"),
    State("memory-output", "data"),
prevent_initial_call=True)
def download_as_excel(n_clicks, table_data):
    if not n_clicks:
        raise PreventUpdate
    else:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('new_excel_file.xlsx', engine="xlsxwriter")
        for df in table_data:
           copytoexcel = pd.DataFrame(table_data[df])
           copytoexcel.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=df)
        writer.save()

        return dcc.send_file('new_excel_file.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I also noticed my layout could just be changed to dcc.Download and it also works